# Error: "Variable used within its own initial value" within closure

Tags: swift, swift5, completionhandler

Why can't I "use a variable within its own initial value" when I am using it in a closure which won't be called until after the variable has been initialized? And how do I avoid this error?

Crude example:

```
class Action {
    var name: String
    var completion: () -> Void

    init(_ name: String, completion: () -> Void ) {
        self.name = name
        self.completion = completion
    }
}

let action = Action("Take", completion: {
    // Do something

    // Then...
    print(action.name) // Error: Variable used within its own initial value
})
```

Another question on SO said "You can use a mutable variable instead, and the closure will capture the variable rather the its value." but this doesn't make sense to me. How do I make the "name" parameter a mutable variable..isn't it already?

Comment: You answered your own question. It's because it's a _closure_. Do you understand what that means? It doesn't wait to find out what `action` will be in the future when the completion handler is called; it captures it right now. But it can't do that because this is the initializer, so there is nothing to capture.

Comment: So how would I get around this?

Comment: That is what the link explains to you. You would have to initialize _first_ and add the completion handler _later_, or else pass a reference to the action down into the completion handler. It's all there. Just click the link.

Comment: I did I just couldn't understand it because the context seemed complicated. Thanks for the info, I think that makes more sense.

Comment: I assure you that the linked question is about _exactly_ the same thing as your question, and the answer answers it.

Comment: I don't doubt it, I just couldn't follow it. I should have mentioned that in my question though because I did read through that question before posting this question.

Comment: "How do I make the "name" parameter a mutable variable..isn't it already?" Actually, it's the `action` that needs to be mutable, and yes it is already because it is a class. But you still can't instantiate it _and_ initialize it with a completion handler that refers back to it, _all in the same code statement_. You need to instantiate it and _then_ give it a completion handler, or else design the completion handler such that a reference to the action (`self`) is passed down into it. And that is exactly what the answer to the linked question tells you. :)

Comment: That makes much more sense to me. So thank you for explaining it even better!